# Vagrant machine not picking network settings

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to start new VM with following settings

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define :master do |master|
    master.vm.box = "saucy64"

    master.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node1"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
    end
    #  master.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.211.55.100"
    master.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node1"
    master.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  end
end
```

If I comment out the network line I get following error:

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it 
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
```

Why machine is not able to pickup network settings?

I tried changing the IP range to see if its clashing with something on my network but it is giving error in all cases.

Vagrant 1.3.1
Virtualbox 4.2

Comment: raising the log level could help you, try to run `vagrant up` with VAGRANT_LOG=debug and then try to analyze the output.

Comment: Still no luck with log level. Can i upload full logs somewhere.Something seems to be wrong with my networking , machine works fine if i comment the network settings

Comment: Could you post a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/) of your debug logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is bug in Virtual box 4.1.16 running on kernel 3.1

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=721786

Due to this its not working properly.

I upgraded it to 4.1.18 and it works fine

Thanks to all those who answered

Comment: The bug happens again in VirtualBox 4.2.18 :(

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your configuration with Vagrant Ubuntu Cloud Image - Saucy amd64. It worked perfectly fine with or without the line `master.vm.network :private_network,ip: "10.211.55.100"`.

Try to use `VBoxManage controlvm UUID|NAME poweroff` to turn off the VM and start it again. Sometimes vagrant fails to halt a VM.

> NOTE: I'v changed external shell script to an inline as I am too lazy to write even a short script ;-)

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.define :master do |master|
    master.vm.box = "saucy64"

    master.vbguest.auto_update = false

    master.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = "vm-cluster-node1"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    end

    master.vm.network :private_network,ip: "10.211.55.100"
    master.vm.hostname = "vm-cluster-node1"
    master.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: "echo hello world"
  end
end
```

`vagrant ssh` into it and I can see 2 interfaces

```
    vagrant@vm-cluster-node1:~$ ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8e:c7:2d  
              inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe8e:c72d/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:265 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:41271 (41.2 KB)  TX bytes:34336 (34.3 KB)

    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b2:8a:f6  
              inet addr:10.211.55.100  Bcast:10.211.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb2:8af6/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:798 (798.0 B)
    vagrant@vm-cluster-node1:~$ hostname
    vm-cluster-node1
    vagrant@vm-cluster-node1:~$ hostname -f
    vm-cluster-node1
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply.Which version of Vagrant you are running. I get this message * Unknown configuration section 'vbguest'. Also can you give example of command you suggested with VBoxManage controlvm UUID|NAME poweroff

Comment: Vagrant 1.3.1. Just remove or comment out the line `master.vbguest.auto_update = false` it's for `vagrant-vbguest`. To get the running vm name or ID `VBoxManage list runningvms`, you can use either name or ID to power it off like `VBoxManage controlvm NAME_OR_ID` poweroff`.